# Outlook 2013 Images Enlarging

Tags: image, email, outlook, outlook-2013, image-enlarge

I have designed a html signature for outlook, it looks perfect in outlook when I send the e-mail and when I receive the e-mail in outlook - however in other e-mail client the images used within the signature are enlarged. The other e-mail clients I used were Mozilla Thunderbird and A webmail I use (mail.com). I have done much research, and found an article suggesting to change the res to 96dpi on my images which I did.

I can't post an image as a new user however you can see them at these links: 
E-mail sent and received in outlook 2013: http://champ.website-admin.net/files/2015/01/e-mailexample.jpg
Received e-mail in thunderbird: http://champ.website-admin.net/files/2015/01/e-mailexample2.jpg

Here's my code:

```
<table width="600" height="140" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family:'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Sans', 'DejaVu Sans', Verdana, sans-serif; color:#d3a25b;">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td style="background-color:#2f2f2f; padding-left:10px; width:400px; height: 140px; line-height:1.2em;">
  <font style="font-size:16px;"><b>Emma Woolward</b></font><br>
  <font style="font-size:11px;"><b><a href="mailto:operations@champresources.com.au">operations@champresources.com.au</a></b><br>
      <b><strong>1300 GO CHAMP</strong></b><br>
      <b>P: 1300 462 426</b><br>
      <b><a href="www.champresources.com.au">www.champresources.com.au</a></b><br></font>
      <font style="color:#2f2f2f; font-size:1px;"><b>.</b><br></font>
      <b><a href="https://www.facebook.com/champresources?fref=ts"><img src="http://champ.website-admin.net/files/2015/01/facebook.jpg" style="float:left;"></a><font style="color:#282828">...<img src="http://champ.website-admin.net/files/2015/01/zeroharm.jpg" style="float:left; margin-left:5px;"></b><br></font></td>
  <td style="width:300px; height: 140px; padding-left:0px;"><img src="http://champ.website-admin.net/files/2015/01/champemailsig.jpg" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's as simple as adding the width and height to the  tag instead of the td.

EG:

`<img width="300" src="http://champ.website-admin.net/files/2015/01/champemailsig.jpg" />`